# __NSCFDictionary stringByDeletingPathExtension crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am displaying a data in a `UITableView` taken from a Web Service .
While trying to add this data in `UITableView` I am getting some weird crash

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary
>   stringByDeletingPathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7f9bc68530e0'

Can anyone tell me what kind of error is this. this is my response

```
<__NSCFArray 0x7fd2846dec80>(
{
    DISTANCE = "2677.2557594500167";
    POPULARITY = 0;
    PRICE = "";
    "bar_id" = 1;
    "event_id" = "";
    "event_name" = "";
    "is_following" = 0;
    "participant_count" = 0;
    "venue_address" = “abc”;
    "venue_image" = "http://dsfdsf.com/uploads/venue_icon/original/8PHHBUbASoZZXdQNOyqL1jKAmd08rowg.jpg";
    "venue_name" = "CLUB";
},
{
    DISTANCE = "2677.2557594500167";
    POPULARITY = 0;
    PRICE = "";
    "bar_id" = 2;
    "event_id" = "";
    "event_name" = "";
    "is_following" = 0;
    "participant_count" = 0;
    "venue_address" = “def”;
    "venue_image" = "http://dsfdsf.com/uploads/venue_icon/original/8PHHBUbASoZZXdQNOyqL1jKAmd08rowg.jpg;
    "venue_name" = “Club";
}
)
```

This is the way i am adding data to `UITableViewCell`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
cell.lbl_eventName.text = [[arrayEventData valueForKey:@"venue_name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: maybe... `cell.lbl_eventName.text = [[arrayEventData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"venue_name"];`, according to your model; because _first_ you need the dictionary _then_ the value for the key.

Comment: May be you are looking for **valueForKeyPath**, `cell.lbl_eventName.text = [[arrayEventData valueForKeyPath:@"venue_name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
cell.lbl_eventName.text = [[arrayEventData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"venue_name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution

```
 NSDictionary*dict       = [Self.arrayEventData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.lbl_eventName.text = [dict valueForKey:@"venue_name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access value of dict in array. First a Dictionary object from

`[Self.arrayEventData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` and call

```
[dict valueForKey:@"venue_name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also handle it with few validation for null or nil value.

```
NSString *strVanue = [[arrayEventData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"venue_name"];

if(strVanue != nil || strVanue != (id)[NSNull null]){

   cell.lbl_eventName.text = strVanue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
NSDictionary *yourDict =[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.lbl_eventName.text = [yourDict valueForKey:@"venue_name"];
```

Comment: Same answer is  given by me.

Comment: Right answers are always same ;)